# Google Storage images not working in Mobile Safari

Tags: image, google-cloud-storage, mobile-safari

I looked hard to make sure this was not a duplicate (there are many other unresolved forums about this problem), but certain images are showing up missing or empty on Mobile Safari from Google Storage but they work fine on desktop computers and other mobile web browsers. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I had the primary Google admin login to the Admin Suite on a Mobile Safari device and visit the image URL directly, and it fixed the images temporarily, but not when I logged out.

Comment: so, this issue is only with certain images, correct? if so, I would suspect on cache issues related to those images, you can discard this using incognito. what is the Safari version that you are using? it would be good to know if this issue happens with all Safari versions or only with an specific one. I would suggest to use the Developer tools on Safari to see if there is any specific error.